# Location of groovy based bean definition configuration in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I have seen that Spring 4 has a feature to define / having a groovy file for bean definitions instead of an XML file. I already have a Spring MVC application with mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml for my bean definitions. But I want to go with Groovy based bean definition for my Spring MVC application. But, I am not sure where to place the groovy file and where do I need to refer it/ configure it to Load the bean definitions properly. Can somebody help or provide refrence?

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4

Comment: Hello, cfrick thanks for providing this reference. Here, I am not able to find the placement of groovy configuration file and how to load on web app startup. That was the reason behind my question. Can you please clarify if I missed to notice anything in this blog?

Answer (score 0):

use the GroovyWebApplicationContext ,

Web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.GroovyWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/dispatcherServlet.groovy</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

[this](https://github.com/li-salvadorlopez/PrimefacesSpring.git) is not a full example, but it is a good start